# Exact search of a string that has parenthesis using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regexes.

I have the following string : `\n(941)\n364\nShackle\n(941)\nRivet\n105\nTop`

Out of this string, I want to extract `Rivet` and I already have `(941)` as a string in a variable.

My thought process was like this:

1. Find all the `(941)`s
2. filter the results by checking if the string after `(941)` is followed by \n, followed by a word, and ending with \n
3. I made a regex for the 2nd part: `\n[\w\s\'\d\-\/\.]+$\n`.

The problem I am facing is that because of the parenthesis in `(941)` the regex is taking 941 as a group. In the 3rd step the regex may be wrong, which I can fix later, but 1st I needed help in finding the 2nd `(941)` so then I can apply the 3rd step on that.

PS.

1. I know I can use python string methods like find and then loop over the searches, but I wanted to see if this can be done directly using regex only.
2. I have tried the following regex: `(?:...)`, `(941){1}` and the make regex literal character `\` like this `\(941\)` with no useful results. Maybe I am using them wrong.

Just wanted to know if it is possible to be done using regex. Though it might be useful for others too or a good share for future viewers.

Thanks!

Comment: to find (941), You can use the reges: "[(]941[)]" enclosing them in bracket will make them a group of character and dont need to be escaped.

Comment: You only want to extract `Rivet`? Because `\s` in the regex for the second part will match newlines (since newlines are whitespace), so it extracts `Rivet\n105`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I did not know that. But thankfully in my case, I am replacing \n with '' post extraction. But might be useful for future viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- You want to avoid matching only digits;
- Want to match a substring made of word-characters (thus including possible digits);

Try to escape the variable and use it in the regular expression through f-string:

```
import re
s = '\n(941)\n364\nShackle\n(941)\nRivet\n105\nTop'
var1 = '(941)'
var2 = re.escape(var1)
m = re.findall(fr'{var2}\n(?!\d+\n)(\w+)', s)[0]
print(m)
```

Prints:

```
Rivet
```

Comment: He says that `(941)` comes from a variable, so it would be helpful if you showed how to insert that into the regexp.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the headsup, I read past that part too quick.

Comment: Thanks for the solution guys. It worked! Also, I did not know about re.escape() method glad you share that. Hopefully, someone in the future will also find this helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If you have text in a variable that should be matched exactly, use `re.escape()` to escape it when substituting into the regexp.

```
s = '\n(941)\n364\nShackle\n(941)\nRivet\n105\nTop'
num = '(941)'
re.findall(rf'(?<=\n{re.escape(num)}\n)[\w\s\'\d\-\/\.]+(?=\n)', s)
```

This puts `(941)\n` in a lookbehind, so it's not included in the match. This avoids a problem with the `\n` at the end of one match overlapping with the `\n` at the beginning of the next.